# Django: How to display specific object to specific user

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django and working on a project where admin have to assign a team to manager and when ever admin assign a team to manager then it will be shown to that specific manager only.I have no idea how can i do this. Please if someone can help please help me.

here is my .html file for admin from where admin can assign team to manager.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>S No.</th>
   <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
    <th>TEAM MEMBER</th>
     <th>EMAIL</th>
      <th>ASSIGN TEAM</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
     {%for team in object%}
       <tr>
         <form id="form_id" method="POST" action = "{% url 'accept' %}">
           {% csrf_token %}
          <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
           <td>{{team.company_name}}</td>
            <td>{{team.team_member}}</td>
             <td>{{team.email}}</td>
              <td>
                 <select name="manager_{{manager.id}}">
                  {% for manager in managers %}
                    <option value ="{{manager.id}}">{{manager.name}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}                                   
                   </select>
               </td>
                 <td>
                     <input class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-round waves-effect" type="submit" value="Assign">
                                </td>
                </tr>
                 {% endfor %}
```

here is my model for the team and manager:

```
class Create_Team(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length= 1000)
    state = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 30)

class manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
```

here is my views.py file for manager and from where the admin is accepting the request:

```
def accept(request):
 obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept') 
  managers = manager.objects.all()
  if request.method == 'POST':
   acc = manager()
   manager_id = int(request.POST.get('manager', 1))
   acc.manager = manager.objects.get(pk=manager_id)

   return render(request, "admin/accept.html", {"object": obj,  "managers": managers})


def superior(request):
return render(request, 'manager/index-3.html')
```

I want that whenever the admin will click on the assign button then that team will be displayed to that manager.Please help me.

Comment: There's no relationship between your `Team` model and your `Manager` model.

Comment: so i have to do something like this Manager = models.ForeignKey('manager', on_delete= models.CASCADE)

Comment: in my team model

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

1. There is no relation from the `Create_Team` to the `manager` model.
2. The `name` attribute on your `<select>` tags do not match the key you using to read from `request.POST`. `manager_{{manager.id}}` renders as `manager_`, so `int(request.POST.get('manager', 1))` will always return 1.
3. The forms in your template do not contain the information which team you want to update.
4. You do not set the attribute `selected` on any `<option>`. As a consequence, the first choice will always be selected.
5. You are not updating any team in your view.

Let's address these issues.

1 - We fix the models by adding a `ForeignKey` from `CreateTeam` to `Manager`. Note that I've renamed the models, which is optional. If you decide to keep your names, adapt it accordingly.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class CreateTeam(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length= 1000)
    state = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 30)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('Manager', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)


class Manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
```

You have to pass two bits of information to the `assign` view: the `id` of the `CreateTeam` you want to assign and the `id` of the `Manager` you want to assign it to.

Note that the `name` attribute of form fields is the key in `request.POST`. These can be any string, just make sure it matches between form and view. It obviously makes life to give them an expressive name.

2 - Sending the `id` of the `Manager` is handled by the `<select>`. Just make sure the `name` attribute matching the key you use in your view.

3 - To send the `id` of the team, you could use a `<button type="submit">` with a name and a value instead of the `<input type="submit">`.

```
<button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-round waves-effect" type="submit" name="team" value="{{ team.id }}">Assign</button>
                            </td>
```

Alternatively, you could use a hidden field.

4 - Finally, you have to have to set the attribute `selected` on the correct `<option>` in your `<select>`. You can do that like this:

```
<option value="{{manager.id}}" {% if team.manager.id == manager.id %}selected{% endif %}
```

Here is the complete template:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S No.</th>
          <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
          <th>TEAM MEMBER</th>
          <th>EMAIL</th>
          <th>ASSIGN TEAM</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {%for team in teams%}
        <tr>
          <form id="form_id" method="POST" action="{% url 'accept' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td>{{team.company_name}}</td>
            <td>{{team.team_member}}</td>
            <td>{{team.email}}</td>
            <td>
              <select name="manager">
              {% for manager in managers %}
              <option value="{{manager.id}}" {% if team.manager.id == manager.id %}selected{% endif %}>{{manager.name}}</option>
              {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-round waves-effect" type="submit" name="team" value="{{ team.id }}">Assign</button>
            </td>
          </form>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

5 - When receiving a POST request, you can assign the manager to the team.
That means you have to use the `id` values to get a `CreateTeam` instance and a `Manager` instance. Then you assign the `Manager` to `createteam.manager` and save the `createteam` object.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render

from .models import CreateTeam, Manager

def accept(request):
    teams = CreateTeam.objects.filter(status='Accept')
    managers = Manager.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        createteam_id = int(request.POST.get('team', 1))
        manager_id = int(request.POST.get('manager', 1))
        createteam = get_object_or_404(teams, pk=createteam_id)
        createteam.manager = get_object_or_404(Manager, pk=manager_id)
        createteam.save()
        redirect('accept')
    return render(request, "admin/accept.html", {"teams": teams,  "managers": managers})
```

There are three things worth highlighting:

1. We use `get_object_or_404` instead of `Model.objects.get`. As the name implies, it returns a 404 if no model can be found. This serves as a simple error handling for edge cases like a user manipulating the form or a manager being deleted while the user has the page open. This error handling could be improved to be more user-friendly, but it's a start.
2. `get_object_or_404` can take a model or a queryset. We load the team instance from the filtered queryset `teams`. Otherwise, a user could manipulate a form and assign a manager to a team that has a status other than `Accept`.
3. After saving the team, we redirect to the `accept` page. This is good practice and ensures that a user can reload the page without seeing the `do you want to resubmit this form` dialog.

Finally, make sure that this view is really only accessible by the admin, e.g. by adding an appropriate [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator.

Comment: sir what is this 2 things are doing name= "team" and value= "{{team.id }}"

Comment: because i have changed my model name so i am confused right now

Comment: is the changes that i have done in your code is write or not

Comment: I've approved your edit and I added a missing line to my code. Also, I suggest you check out https://pep8.org/, especially the section on naming conventions

Comment: the edit that i proposed was right or not because i was confused that it was right or not..

Comment: Yes, your proposed edit was right and I have approved it

Comment: ok then i will check that it is working or not and i will you afterwards

Comment: there is an error in this line saying "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' " 
 createteam_id = int(request.POST.get('Create_Team', 1))

Comment: we are doing some thing wrong can you tell me where i am lacking

Comment: Check the HTML of the page that the `value` attribute of your `<button>` element actually contains the id of the corresponding team.

Comment: can you reset the changes that i have done to your code because i think my changes are wrong

Comment: yes it contains the id of the respective team but it is not updating in the database

Comment: I've expanded my answer, I hope it is clear now. Sorry for not getting back earlier.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i make a  manager because in my existing code i have given extra permission to user so that he should work as manager.

Comment: But now my biggest problem is that how can i sync that user to manager. Is there any way to do this or i have to do it in a other way

Comment: I think that's worth posting as a different question. If this question has been solved, I'd appreciate if you accept my answer